# Can I be a commercial pilot if I've had a dental filling?

Tags: flight-training, medical

Is there something like a health requirement in serious airlines? Or is it just a myth? How are potential pilots screened when it comes down to physical requirements?

Comment: The appropriate answer to this question would depend on what country you are asking about since each country has their own rules, and they aren't the same. Please update your question to indicate where you live.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the [mouth and throat requirements](http://flightphysical.com/Exam-Guide/HEENT/Mouth-28.htm) for a pilot physical.

The main thing is that it shouldn't affect your ability to fly (i.e. having pain) and ability to communicate over the radio.

Commercial pilots who don't fly regular schedules need a Class 2 medical certificate. Regular schedule commercial pilots need a Class 1.

- [FAA Class 2 medical requirements](http://flightphysical.com/part67/Class2/67subc.htm)
- [FAA Class 1 medical requirements](http://flightphysical.com/part67/Class1/67subb.htm)

Answer (score 4):

The major requirement for dental fillings as far as aviation (or diving) is concerned is there not be a trapped air pocket under the filling (this could cause problems for divers or pilots as the pressure changes may cause discomfort. (It's called [barodontalgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barodontalgia) - pressure-induced tooth pain.)

Air pockets are something your dentist will try to avoid anyway because they promote further decay & will eventually require more work on the tooth, so if your dentist is competent you shouldn't have any problems.
If you do notice discomfort while flying mention it to your dentist - an X-Ray can usually identify the problem in a few minutes, and your dentist can then take care of it (replace the filling, or if it's a new cavity treat it appropriately).

Answer (score 2):

Dental fillings, false teeth, implants are all permitted so long as the mouth is healthy and there are no abcesses.

Commercial pilots need a first class medical certificate.  I don't have that reference here with me now, but perhaps someone can post either a link to the requirements for a first class medical, or list the requirements here.

Comment: In the US, commercial pilots require a 2nd class medical certificate.  Airline pilots require a 1st class medical.

Comment: Dan, you are right.  I made the assumption that the OP's "serious airline" would require a first class medical.